# how to identify query statement has a subquery in it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Developing an C# project for SQL Training and giving different exercises based on training on each topic. One of the exercise is to write a query using Sub-Query.  which needs to be evaluated whether the user has used/implemented Sub query in the Query Statment.

Q: Write a sql query to show the SalesOrderID,LineTotal,average LineTotal from the Sales.SalesOrderDetail table using Sub query

```
Select SalesOrderID,LineTotal [LineTotal],
(Select AVG(LineTotal) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail) as [AverageLineTotal] 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

`[AverageLineTotal]` is an sub query.

Can we identify it by any means?? like execution plan Or SP to identify it has an sub query in the statement

Is there any way to identify it through execution Plans??

Comment: Any particular reason why you are interested in finding subqueries? You can rewrite a subquery using a join in some cases.

Comment: Am giving an exercise to an user/student to use an SubQuery in an sql Statement, and trying to validate if he does it correctly using an C# code.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to correctly distinguish a subquery from another joining operators without a complex SQL parser. You can try asking in dba.stackexchange.com, maybe there's someone can come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a c# project you can parse the query with regex to find if the query contains (select {any other text}).

```
public static void Main()
{
    var sql = @"Select SalesOrderID,LineTotal [LineTotal],(Select AVG(LineTotal) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail) as [AverageLineTotal] from Sales.SalesOrderDetail";
    Console.WriteLine(DoesSqlContainSubquery(sql));
}

public bool DoesSqlContainSubquery(string sql)
{
    var regexTest = new Regex(@"\( *Select .*\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var containsSubquery = regexTest.IsMatch(sql);
    return containsSubquery;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing ad-hoc scripts is inherently complex due to the plethora T-SQL constructs and options. That being said, a robust method for targeted use cases is parsing scripts with the [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom).

Below is an example PowerShell script that uses the script DOM assembly from the [official Microsoft Dacfx NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/), downloading and extracting it if needed.

```
# Add TSqlScript DOM assembly reference, downloading and extracting to the specified location if needed
$scriptDomAssemblyPath = "C:\Temp\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"
$scriptDomNuGetUrl = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/150.4384.2"
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($scriptDomAssemblyPath)) {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scriptDomNuGetUrl
    if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
        throw "Unable to download Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom NuGet package: $response.StatusCode : $response.StatusDescription"
    }
    $tempZipFilePath = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())/$([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()).zip"
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tempZipFilePath, $response.Content)
    $response.BaseResponse.Dispose()
    $tempUnzipFolderPath = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())/$([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())"
    Expand-Archive -Path $tempZipFilePath -DestinationPath $tempUnzipFolderPath
    $tempZipFilePath | Remove-Item
    Move-Item "$tempUnzipFolderPath\lib\net46\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" "$scriptDomAssemblyPath"
    $tempUnzipFolderPath | Remove-Item -Recurse
}
Add-Type -Path $scriptDomAssemblyPath

# script to be parsed
$scriptText = @"
Select SalesOrderID,LineTotal [LineTotal],
(Select AVG(LineTotal) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail) as [AverageLineTotal] 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
"@

#parse script
$parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql150Parser($true)
$parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
$scriptReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($scriptText)
$script = $parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
if($parseErrors.Count -gt 0) {
    throw "$($parseErrors.Count) parsing errors"
}

# sanity check for expected SELECT query
if(($script.Batches.Count -ne 1) -or ($script.Batches[0].Statements.Count -ne 1) -or ($script.Batches[0].Statements[0].QueryExpression -eq $null)) {
    throw "script with single SELECT statement expected"
}

# find scalar subquery expression in select list
$subQueryFound = $false
foreach($selectElement in $script.Batches[0].Statements[0].QueryExpression.SelectElements) {
    if($selectElement.Expression.ToString() -eq "Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ScalarSubquery") {
        $subQueryFound = $true
        break
    }
}

# show if subquery was used
if($subQueryFound) {
    Write-Host "A subquery is used"
}
else {
    Write-Host "A subquery is not used"
}
```